# Assignment makes pointer from integer warning

Tags: c, header, gcc-warning

Header:

```
#ifndef BIT_H_INCLUDE_GUARD
#define BIT_H_INCLUDE_GUARD

typedef unsigned char byte;

typedef struct{
    size_t* size;
    byte* map;
} bit;

bit* bdcteate(byte* size);

#endif /* BIT_H_INCLUDE_GUARD */
```

source:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bit.h"

bit* bdcreate(byte* size){
    bit* d;
    byte i;
    size_t s = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < size[0]; i++){
        s += (size_t) size[i];
    }
    if(!(d = malloc(sizeof(bit)))){
        return (bit*) NULL;
    }
    if(!(d->size = malloc(sizeof(size_t)))){
        return (bit*) NULL;
    }
    if(!(d->map = malloc(s * sizeof(byte)))){
        return (bit*) NULL;
    }
    *d->size = s;
    return (bit*) d;
}
```

main:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bit.h"

void main(void){
    byte *b, i;
    byte size = 9;
    b = malloc((size+1) * sizeof(byte));
    b[0] = size;
    for(i = 1; i <= size; i++){
        b[i] = (b[i-1] + 10);
    }   

    bit* dict;
    if(!(dict = bdcreate(b))){ /* warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

As you see in the commented line, I get "warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" although I try to explicitly state that I am returning a pointer.

I'm compiling with gcc (`gcc -o test main.c bit.c`) and the program **seems** to run OK.

Should I ignore that or is it going to come back and bite me while I sleep?

Comment: Make sure you pay attention to all warnings, including warnings about implicit declaration.

Comment: Also, you will have a memory leak if either the 2nd or 3rd malloc fails.

Comment: yup, I know about the memory leaks but i thought this piece of code is enough already!!!

Comment: You should add the gcc options `-Wall` and `-Werror` so you can catch this kind of thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your header:

```
bit* bdcteate(byte* size);
        ^ this is a typo
```

Which means the compiler will infer a default signature for `bdcreate` in your main, and the default signature returns an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in bit.h.  "bdcteate" should be "bdcreate".  So there's no forward declaration for bdcreate in bit.h, which means the compiler assumes the call in main returns int.  The code works anyway because on the CPU you're using either an int is large enough to contain a pointer or the bits stripped off don't invalidate the resulting pointer.